# Generating Multiple Lags in R with shorter code

Tags: r, performance, functional-programming, lag

Let's assume that I have a data.frame named W that is 2 time-ordered variables Y and X that are ordered from observation 1 to 10:

```
Y<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
X<- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
W<- data.frame(Y,X)
```

My goal is to create a lagged version of W.  The following code works fine using the shift function in package DataCombine:

```
Wl1<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-1, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl1)<- paste(colnames(W),".l1",sep="")

Wl2<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-2, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl2)<- paste(colnames(W),".l2",sep="")

Wl3<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-3, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl3)<- paste(colnames(W),".l3",sep="")

Wl4<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-4, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl4)<- paste(colnames(W),".l4",sep="")

Wl5<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-5, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl5)<- paste(colnames(W),".l5",sep="")

Wl6<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-6, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl6)<- paste(colnames(W),".l6",sep="")

Wl7<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-7, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl7)<- paste(colnames(W),".l7",sep="")

Wl8<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-8, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl8)<- paste(colnames(W),".l8",sep="")

Wl9<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-9, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl9)<- paste(colnames(W),".l9",sep="")

Wl10<- sapply(W,shift,shiftBy=-10, reminder=FALSE)
colnames(Wl10)<- paste(colnames(W),".l10",sep="")

Wlagged<- data.frame(Wl1,Wl2,Wl3,Wl4,Wl5,Wl6,Wl7,Wl8,Wl9,Wl10)
```

I need assistance in making this code more compact and less prone to error.  I am guessing that some form of apply can be used (as opposed to a loop statement), but I do not yet understand how to better use these functions.  Thank you all!

Comment: This might be a good read in your case: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(W)
lag(z, -(1:10))
```

Comment: Great option, thank you for introducing me to the zoo package.  One thing: when I run the code you presented, I get a zoo series from 2 to 10, where observation 1 is dropped.  My hope is to also retain the original data of W.  Is there a way to do this so that I can also have the non-lagged data present?  The goal is to retain the original size of W.  Maybe just writ an additional line of code that adds a top row of NAs?

Comment: Use `na.pad = TRUE`.  See `?zoo.lag`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less elegant solution which uses only base R

```
W[paste0(colnames(W), ".l", rep(seq_len(10), each = 2))] <- 
sapply(seq_len(10), function(x) sapply(W, function(y) c(rep(NA, x), head(y, -x))))
W
#     Y  X Y.l1 X.l1 Y.l2 X.l2 Y.l3 X.l3 Y.l4 X.l4 Y.l5 X.l5 Y.l6 X.l6 Y.l7 X.l7 Y.l8 X.l8 Y.l9 X.l9 Y.l10 X.l10
# 1   1 11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 2   2 12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 3   3 13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 4   4 14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 5   5 15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 6   6 16    5   15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 7   7 17    6   16    5   15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 8   8 18    7   17    6   16    5   15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 9   9 19    8   18    7   17    6   16    5   15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11   NA   NA    NA    NA
# 10 10 20    9   19    8   18    7   17    6   16    5   15    4   14    3   13    2   12    1   11    NA    NA
```

Comment: Although the zoo solution is shorter, I very much appreciate this longer solution.  It helps me get a better idea of how to write more complicated routines.  Is using sapply within sapply like running a for loop within a for loop?

Comment: It is similar, but it isn't such a big deal as the outer loop is very small (10 iterations)